# Google AdMob native campaign ad not displayed

Tags: android, ios, admob

I am trying to test a campaign ad on an iOS device and the problem is that I get some test ad, if I set `testDevices`, or real one if not, but not the one I've created for campaign. Android application is working fine and displaying desired ad. What might be the problem? I've tried to use android ad and application ids, but still getting some test ads, not the one from campaign.

Code sample

```
self.adLoader = [[GADAdLoader alloc]
                  initWithAdUnitID:@"ad_unit_id"
                  rootViewController:self
                  adTypes:@[kGADAdLoaderAdTypeUnifiedNative]
                  options:@[]];
self.adLoader.delegate = self;
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
[request setTestDevices:@[ @"test_device_id" ]];
```

Comment: Did you refer this https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

Comment: @core114 yes, everything works perfect with test ids, it even displays real ads, but how should one test its campaign ads.